# Why is computed value not updated after vuex store update?

Tags: vue.js, computed-properties, vuex

I got a `printerList` computed property that should be re-evaluated after `getPrinters()` resolve, but it look like it's not.

[sources are online](https://github.com/Coaxis-ASP/opt/tree/f1267a6a4f1202a3db710b1ee0639996730186c1/frontend/src): [optbox.component.vue](https://github.com/Coaxis-ASP/opt/blob/f1267a6a4f1202a3db710b1ee0639996730186c1/frontend/src/pages/optboxes/optbox.component.vue), [vuex](https://github.com/Coaxis-ASP/opt/tree/f1267a6a4f1202a3db710b1ee0639996730186c1/frontend/src/vuex), [optboxes.service.js](https://github.com/Coaxis-ASP/opt/blob/f1267a6a4f1202a3db710b1ee0639996730186c1/frontend/src/services/optboxes.service.js)

#### Component

```
<template>
    <div v-for="printer in printersList">
        <printer :printer="printer" :optbox="optbox"></printer>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
…
created() { this.getPrinters(this.optbox.id); },
    computed: {
        printersList() {
            var index = optboxesService.getIndex(this.optboxesList, this.optbox.id);
            return this.optboxesList[index].printers
        }
    },
    vuex: {
        actions: { getPrinters: actions.getPrinters,},
        getters: { optboxesList: getters.retrieveOptboxes}
    }
<script>
```

#### Actions

```
getPrinters({dispatch}, optboxId) {
    printers.get({optbox_id: optboxId}).then(response => {
        dispatch('setPrinters', response.data.optbox, response.data.output.channels);
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
        logging.error(this.$t('printers.get.failed'))
    });
},
```

#### Mutations

```
setPrinters(optboxes, optboxId, printers) {
    var index = this.getIndex(optboxes, optboxId);
    optboxes[index] = {...optboxes[index], printers: printers }
},
```

#### Question

Why does the `printerList` computed property isn't re-evaluated (i.e. the `v-for` is empty)

Comment: Does the `vuex` debugger show the correct values for `Printers`? For me, it rings an alarm that mutations are passing the state around instead of handling it by themselves.

Comment: @HectorLorenzo if you mean the vue devtools tool,yes, but it's not commited

Answer (score 31):

It is due to this line:
`optboxes[index] = {...optboxes[index], printers: printers }`.

You are directly setting item with index, which [can't be observed by Vue](http://vuejs.org/guide/list.html#Caveats)

Try splicing the old item from array and pushing the new one.

Comment: Splicing worked for me. For example, in my mutation:  state.orders.splice(index, 1, payload)

Answer (score 18):

You could do this:

```
Vue.set(optboxesList[index], 'printers', printers )
```

Comment: this is what fixed it for me. I was setting the state directly from within my mutations. Once I started using Vue.set then everything became magically reactive again

Answer (score 1):

you need force update

```
setPrinters(optboxes, optboxId, printers) {
    const index = this.getIndex(optboxes, optboxId);
    const newVal = {...optboxes[index], printers: printers }
    Vue.set(optboxes, index, newVal);
},
```