# Vuex not updating computed variable mapped using mapState

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuex

I [looked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40513389/computed-property-not-updating-from-vuex-store-object) [at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38819289/why-is-computed-value-not-updated-after-vuex-store-update) [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40707578/vuex-how-to-render-data-from-store-using-v-for) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40645419/data-not-populating-in-vue-app) to figure out what I am 
doing wrong. Everything looks to me setup correctly.

**GOAL**

Based upon the value of **COMPONENT A** change hide/display content using `v-show` in **DEPENDENT COMPONENT**.

**PROBLEM**

Inside **TextField Component**, there is an input that triggers a mutation on my `vuex store`. **Dependent Component** has a `computed` value that listens to changes on the `vuex store`.

When typing in my **TextField Component**, I can verify by using the [Vue.js extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd) that the mutations are triggering as expected.

HOWEVER, there is no change on the page.

**COMPONENT A**

```
<template>
  <div class="field">

    <input type="text" :name="field.name" v-bind:value="value" v-on:input="updateValue($event.target.value)">

  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['field'],
  methods: {
    updateValue: function (value) {
      this.$store.commit('UPDATE_USER_INPUT', {'key': this.field.name, 'value': value})
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**MUTATION**

```
UPDATE_USER_INPUT (state, payload) {
  state.userInput[payload['key']] = payload['value']
}
```

**DEPENDENT COMPONENT**

```
<template>
  <div class="field-item">
    {{ userInput }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex'

export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapState([
      'userInput'
    ])
  }
}
</script>
```

No matter what I try, `{{ userInput }}` remains empty: `{}` until I navigate my route back to the same location. But there is no computed value listener being triggered.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you are setting a new `key` within the vuex state then you will need to use:

```
UPDATE_USER_INPUT (state, payload) {
  Vue.set(state.userInput, payload.key, payload.value)
}
```

Otherwise it won't be reactive.

See [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set).

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you @GuyC. I am adding a link to the documentation about this to your answer.

Comment: If I could have upvoted your answer 10 times, I would have done it! Thanks.

Comment: MAN!!!! 100 likes if I had that option. You saved me from a deep pitfall

Comment: I'm setting a basic string value but mapState does not update, where mapGetters works as expected. Weird?

Comment: Upvoted! I wish I could upvote you more than once. That was awesome.